# Basic Boolean Question in Excel VBA: Output -1

Tags: excel, vba, boolean, basic

True * True * True = -1

When I multiply an odd number of boolean variables equal to true, the result is -1. Why is this?

Isn't this:
TRUE * TRUE * TRUE

the same as this:

1 * 1 * 1?

Why does vba return a -1, and Excel return a 1 when evaluating this?

I've been using writing code like this

If Asb(TRUE * TRUE * TRUE) =1 then...

or this

If TRUE * TRUE * TRUE <> 0 then ...

I would like to understand why the code behaves this way. Thanks in advance for an explanation.

Comment: In VBA, True is literally defined as -1 and False is literally defined as 0.

Comment: For example, in the Immediate Window of the VB Editor, try these: ? True -1 and also ? False -1

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why would you want to multiply a boolean value?

Answer (score 1):

> Boolean data type A data type with only two possible values, True (-1)
>   or False (0). Boolean variables are stored as 16-bit (2-byte) numbers.
>   See data type summary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#data-type

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/boolean-data-type

Comment: Thanks. I'd though of the value of true to be 1. Thank you for the clarification. Any idea why in excel if I multiply 3 true boolean values the result is (1) and not (-1)?

Comment: Excel treats the value 0 as false, and any other numerical value as true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stick to -1 and 0 for true and false.  To confirm what your language uses for true, simply assign zero to a variable (false), doesn't have to be boolean, then print not(variable) to determine what true is.  This does not work the other way around unless the original value is -1.  The bitwise not operator reverses all bits, and -1 is a two bit number where all bits are set, zero all bits are cleared.  If you assign a variable with any other non-zero number, using bitwise not will still return true when converted to boolean.

One in binary is fifteen zeroes and a one.  Flip all those bits and you get fifteen ones followed by a zero, which is a negative value because that first bit denotes negative number, but it won't be negative one.  Flipping all the bits again returns it to its original value - one.

Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

In Vba  Boolean
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=netframework-4.8)

> ```
> False  :  0
> True  :  ..., -3,-2.5,-2,-1.5, -1,1.5,2,1.5,3,......
> ```

Since Double except 0 is true, code can be written in various formats as shown below.

```
Sub testString()
    Dim myBool As Boolean
    Dim str As String
    Dim n As Double

    str = "Mountain"

    n = InStr(str, "t") '<~~ 5
    If InStr(str, "t") > 0 Then
        MsgBox n
    End If

    '** below same
    If InStr(str, "t") Then
        MsgBox n
    End If

    '** below same
    If n Then
        MsgBox n
    End If

End Sub
```

### Boolean Debug test

[image]